# Working with Ruby and APIs

Tags: ruby, api

I am pretty new to working with Ruby, especially with APIs but I've been trying to get the [Darksky API](https://github.com/darkskyapp/darksky-ruby) to work, but I'm afraid I'm missing something obvious with how I'm using it.

Here is what I have

```
require 'darksky'

darksky = Darksky::API.new('my api key')

forecast = darksky.forecast('34.0500', '118.2500')

forecast
```

When I run this from the command line nothing happens. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you signed up and got your API Key ?

Comment: Yep. Even when the API key is entered it just doesn't return any data. Gem is installed as well.

Comment: What have you checked? Your code looks ok. Is your API key working and creates a valid `darksky` object? Do you know if they have global weather coverage since you're asking for China? What about if you try something like `darksky.interesting`?

Comment: I am not sure how to check if it creates a valid darksky object, but as far as I can tell my API key is valid. I copied straight from the dashboard.

Comment: Could be wrong, but you should try with a lat/lon in the US. http://darkskyapp.com/support/ the only supported country in the map is the US.

Comment: Yea, I tried a US location (34.1803, 118.3283 or Burbank, CA) and I'm still getting `nil`.

Comment: I think the API is broken. Using direct requests to Forecast.io works, even using the OP's location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply using `forecast` isn't going to do anything. You need to use `puts` at a minimum:

```
puts forecast
```

Or, see if Ruby's object pretty-printer can return something more interesting:

```
require 'pp'
pp forecast
```

---

Digging in further, I think their API doesn't work. Based on their examples, using a valid key and their location samples, plus the locations from their source site Forecast.io, also returns nil.

Using the REST interface directly from Forecast.io's site does return JSON. JSON is very easy to work with in Ruby, so it's a good way to go.

Here's some code to test the API, and Forecast.io's REST interface:

```
API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
LOCATION = %w[37.8267 -122.423]

require 'darksky'
darksky = Darksky::API.new(API_KEY)
forecast = darksky.forecast(*LOCATION)
forecast # => nil

brief_forecast = darksky.brief_forecast(*LOCATION)
brief_forecast # => nil

require 'json'
require 'httparty'
URL = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/#{ API_KEY }/37.8267,-122.423"
puts URL
# >> https://api.forecast.io/forecast/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/37.8267,-122.423

puts HTTParty.get(URL).body[0, 80]
# >> {"latitude":37.8267,"longitude":-122.423,"timezone":"America/Los_Angeles","offse
```

Notice that `LOCATION` is `37.8267,-122.423` in both cases, which is Alcatraz according to the Forecast.io site. Also notice that the `body` output displayed is a JSON string.

Pass the returned JSON to the Ruby's JSON class like:

```
JSON[returned_json]
```

to get it parsed back into a Ruby Hash. Using OpenURI (because it comes with Ruby) instead of HTTParty, and passing it to JSON for parsing looks like:

```
body = open(URL).read
puts JSON[body]
```

Comment: When I use 

`pp forecast`

it returns

`nil`

When I use 

`puts forecast`

it returns nothing

I changed my coordinates to the ones used in the example, so they should work but don't.

Comment: So, in theory my code should have worked? I'll have to take some time to digest your suggested code example, but thanks for providing it. It's appreciated.

Comment: No, your code won't work from my tests, but that's not your fault. I think the darksky API is broken, because, using their examples, I get nil values, just like you do. Using the same location and connecting to Forecast.io works fine, so I'd say to skip the API and go to the source.